# Rotate image in tkinter for game

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am creating a game in python using Tkinter canvases, and I need to rotate a sprite in the game, I have attempted using PIL's
`'image'.rotate()`
however the loss of quality is far too high and it wont perform more than about 20 transforms before it starts to lag badly. Can this be fixed or are there any other options aside from making 100s of images by hand?
Here is my code:

```
shipPIL = shipPIL.rotate(math.degrees(increment), expand=True)
shipTex = ImageTk.PhotoImage(shipPIL)
canvas.itemconfig(self.object, image=shipTex)
```

increment = pi/20

Comment: tkinter isnt really meant for this ... try something like pygame or libtcod  or something that is actually designed around games to begin with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should be saving the original image as a clean copy, and rotating it starting from the original each time. Depending on what you're doing, it may also be a good idea to cache the various rotations somewhere instead of calculating it each time.

EDIT: and TKinter is for GUI applications, not games. I recommend Pygame instead.

Comment: To go into more detail on why this is failing: Each time you rotate an image, you lose information, as there is no 1-1 mapping between old and new pixels. When you repeatedly rotate the same image, the errors add up quickly.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I don't know why I didn't think to rotate it from the original, thank you. Also, just to say, I've already planned out the entire thing to work with Tkinter, and have no experience with Pygame and since my plan is being assessed I think I'll stick at the moment, in the future I will use Pygame don't worry :)